# What is a silver tip roast?

Tags: food-identification, cut-of-meat

I got this roast called a silver tip roast. I’m led to believe it’s the shoulder. Can anyone confirm this or know what it is?

[image: silver tip roast]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a silver tip roast is a cut from the shoulder.  It is generally a lean cut.  It is the cut used for most deli sliced roast beef in the US.  Most recipes I see sear, then roast.  Because it is a lean cut, it is best to monitor the internal temperature as you cook.  It will easily become dry when over cooked.